# Using regex to match string between two strings while excluding strings

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Following on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990790/using-regex-to-match-string-between-two-strings) in which I asked:

> How can I use a regular expression to match text that is between two strings, where those two strings are themselves enclosed two other strings, with any amount of text between the inner and outer enclosing strings?

I got this answer:

```
/outer-start.*?inner-start(.*?)inner-end.*?outer-end/
```

I would now like to know how to exclude certain strings from the text between the outer enclosing strings and the inner enclosing strings.

For example, if I have this text:

> **outer-start** some text **inner-start** *text-that-i-want* **inner-end** some more text **outer-end**

I would like 'some text' and 'some more text' not to contain the word 'unwanted'.

In other words, this is OK:

> **outer-start** some wanted text **inner-start** *text-that-i-want* **inner-end** some more wanted text **outer-end**

But this is not OK:

> **outer-start** some unwanted text **inner-start** *text-that-i-want* **inner-end** some more unwanted text **outer-end**

Or to explain further, the expression between outer and inner delimiters in the previous answer above should exclude the word 'unwanted'.

Is this easy to match using regexes?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the first and last (but not the middle) `.*?` with `(?:(?!unwanted).)*?`.  (Where `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, and `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead.)

However, this quickly ends up with corner cases and caveats in any real (instead of example) use, and if you would ask about what you're really doing (with real examples, even if they're simplified, instead of made up examples), you'll likely get better answers.

Comment: That's a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `.*?` with

```
 ([^u]|u[^n]|un[^w]|unw[^a]|unwa[^n]|unwan[^t]|unwant[^e]|unwante[^d])*?
```

This is a solution in "pure" regex; the language you are using might allow you to use some more elegant construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily do that with plain regexes, but some systems such as Perl have extensions that make it easier. One way is to use a negative look-ahead assertion:

```
/outer-start(?:u(?!nwanted)|[^u])*?inner-start(.*?)inner-end.*?outer-end/
```

The key is to split up the "unwanted" into ("u" not followed by "nwanted") or (not "u"). That allows the pattern to advance, but will still find and reject all "unwanted" strings.

People may start hating your code if you do much of this though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tola, resurrecting this question because it had a fairly simple regex solution that wasn't mentioned. This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

The idea is to build an alternation (a series of `|`) where the left sides **match what we don't want** in order to get it out of the way...  then the last side of the `|` matches what we do want, and captures it to Group 1. If Group 1 is set, you retrieve it and you have a match.

So what do we not want?

First, we want to eliminate the whole outer block if there is `unwanted` between `outer-start` and `inner-start`. You can do it with:

```
outer-start(?:(?!inner-start).)*?unwanted.*?outer-end
```

This will be to the left of the first `|`. It matches a whole outer block.

Second, we want to eliminate the whole outer block if there is `unwanted` between `inner-end` and `outer-end`. You can do it with:

```
outer-start(?:(?!outer-end).)*?inner-end(?:(?!outer-end).)*?unwanted.*?outer-end
```

This will be the middle `|`. It looks a bit complicated because we want to make sure that the "lazy" `*?` does not jump over the end of a block into a different block.

Third, we match and capture what we want. This is:

```
inner-start\s*(text-that-i-want)\s*inner-end
```

So the whole regex, in free-spacing mode, is:

```
(?xs)
outer-start(?:(?!inner-start).)*?unwanted.*?outer-end # dont want this
| # OR (also don't want that)
outer-start(?:(?!outer-end).)*?inner-end(?:(?!outer-end).)*?unwanted.*?outer-end
| # OR capture what we want
inner-start\s*(text-that-i-want)\s*inner-end
```

On [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/fL1qY9), look at the Group 1 captures on the right: It contains what we want, and only for the right block.

In Perl and PCRE (used for instance in PHP), you don't even have to look at Group 1: you can force the regex to skip the two blocks we don't want. The regex becomes:

```
(?xs)
(?: # non-capture group: the things we don't want
outer-start(?:(?!inner-start).)*?unwanted.*?outer-end # dont want this
| # OR (also don't want that)
outer-start(?:(?!outer-end).)*?inner-end(?:(?!outer-end).)*?unwanted.*?outer-end
)
(*SKIP)(*F) # we don't want this, so fail and skip
| # OR capture what we want
inner-start\s*\Ktext-that-i-want(?=\s*inner-end)
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/jG5aJ2): it directly matches what you want.

The technique is explained in full detail in the question and article below.

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the last .*? with: (?!(.*unwanted text.*))

Did it work?

Comment: If you're unsure (and even if you think you're sure), you should test your pattern locally (or on a site like http://codepad.org/), which is why regex questions need good examples (both passing and failing).