# Extract words between two words with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string:

> 8 nights you doodle poodle

I wish to retrieve every thing between `nights` and `poodle`, so in the above example, the output should be `you doodle`.

I'm using the below regex. Please can someone point out what I may be doing wrong?

```
if (preg_match("nights\s(.*)\spoodle", "8 nights you doodle poodle", $matches1)) {
    echo $matches1[0]."<br />"; 
}
```

Comment: Smells way to much like homework.  Go and learn regex.  Yes I know it is hard, but once you grok what all those weird match strings are about the better of you will be as a programmer.

Comment: @FlyingGuy - [Homework questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) are ok, as long as they are labeled `homework`.

Comment: If it was, I wouldn't have posted my answer.

Comment: @Shredder, your answer is rubbish anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're close, but you're accessing the wrong index on `$matches1`. `$matches1[0]` will return the string that matched in preg_match();

Try `$matches1[1]`;

Also, you need to enclose your regex in `/` characters;

```
if (preg_match("/nights\s(.*)\spoodle/", "8 nights you doodle poodle", $matches1)) {
    echo $matches1[1]."<br />"; 
}
```

Output

```
you doodle<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this

```
if (preg_match("/nights\s(.*)\spoodle/", "8 nights you doodle poodle", $matches1)) {
    echo $matches1[1]."<br />"; 
}
```

Check out rubular.com to test your regular expressions. Here is another relevant question:

[Using regex to match string between two strings while excluding strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993173/using-regex-to-match-string-between-two-strings-while-excluding-strings)